# Visual Studio is stealing focus

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2012, focus

Since some days Visual Studio is stealing the focus. The weird thing is, this happens when using other applications in Windows (such as Chrome) but also when working in Visual Studio (such as typing).

My considerations so far:

- It only happens when VS is running.
- Happens in VS 2012 Premium **and** in VS 2012 Professional.
- Also happens in Safe Mode.
- Tried reinstalling. No success.
- Uninstalled 3rd-party extensions. No success.
- The focus goes to *"nowhere"* - I don't see any application or window having the focus. Also a `[Windows]+[Array up]` does not maximize anything.
- `[Alt]+[Space]` has no effect.
- `[Alt]+[F4]` has no effect.
- I'm running Windows 8.1.

Does anyone have an idea what the cause is, or what I can do to further analyze it?

Comment: You've exhausted everything you could reasonably do to diagnose this.  Time to consider that it isn't VS doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems I found the cause by disabling background tasks step-by-step. The focus stealing was gone when I killed the **QuickSet** application on my Dell XPS 13. I also read on Dell forums that others were having similar problems with focus stealing. The strange thing is, that it only happened when VS was running.

But anyway, as VS is more important to me I decided to split up with **QuickSet**. :'-(